# Как убрать изображение если в запросе отсутствует ссылка на него?

Tags: ios, swift

Я делаю парсинг фотографий в `tableview`
Я хочу чтобы если в запросе в поле `image` было пусто, то ячейка бы убирала изображение из нее и оставляла только текст
Раньше я делал это так, я просто создавал аутлет на высоту изображения, и менял его на ноль если изображение отсутствует.
Сейчас я не использую ограничение по высоте для изображения в ячейке, поэтому незнаю как скрывать его
Я делаю `isHidden = true`, но остается пустое пространство
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как избавиться от пустого пространства?

Comment: Зачем Вы убрали ограничение по высоте изображения?

Comment: Как у вас верстка ячейки организована?
Можно в UIStackView добавить аватарку, имя и дату. И он сам будет менять Layout (двигать имя и дату), когда вы скроете изображение (isHiddent = true).

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию **heightForRowAt**.

Убедитесь что ваш UIViewController является делегатом UITableViewDelegate, например вот так:

```
ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

}
```

И переопределите функцию heightForRowAt:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var cellHeight: CGFloat = 50
    if yourData[indexPath.row].image == nil {
        cellHeight = 20
    }
    return cellHeight
}
```

Где yourData - ваш массив с данными.